# How do I log in in TTY1

Tags: login, tty

I tried to follow the steps on [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears), but whenever I do, I don't know how to log in when it prompts me. How do I log on? I run 14.04 Trusty.

Comment: http://linux.about.com/od/linux101/l/blnewbie5_1.htm

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> ...
2. Write your username (lowercase, the name of the user folder in `/home`) and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Write your password (nothing will appear) and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. If your password and username are correct, you are now logged in.

Comment: Note that only CTRL + ALT + F[1-6] will open a text terminal on Ubuntu (See `/etc/default/console-setup` and the line ACTIVE_CONSOLES="/dev/tty[1-6]")